# Mvvm - Updating Binding takes too long

Tags: performance, mvvm, binding

I have a 5 ViewModels. Every view has their own VM. When I start the program, the ViewModel changes the bindings, i.e.

```
private string _bruttolohn;
public string Bruttolohn
{
    get { return _bruttolohn; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value != _bruttolohn)
            {
                _bruttolohn = value;
                Calculate();
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Bruttolohn);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Bruttolohn = some value I put in to calculate and set the new values. I have ~100 other propertys, which are all using Binding. If I start the program, the calculation is fine and works fast! But when I change the View (All views are in a ContentControl. If I click on a button, the view is being changed like this: MyContent.Content = new FirstView();). Now here's the problem: If I change the view ~30 times, the ViewModel needs way too long to set the bindings. Why!?
+ If I debug and I'm at this point:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Bruttolohn);
```

Error pops up: ObservableObject.cs is missing...?

Comment: (Try to stick to one question!) Try to remove the calculation from the property getter.

Comment: Sorry "property setter" if the bindings are TwoWay the Views are setting the property and are calling the Calculate method many times.

Comment: The calculation is being called max. twice when I change the value (since it'll only set when it's LostFocus). I could call 'Calculation()' only when the user clicks on a button, but it's still irritating me why the Calculation at the beginning is 'super fast' and when I change the Content of my ContentControl and try to Calculate again, it's taking 3+ seconds to calculate.

Comment: Did you realy pin it down to the calculate being slow or is something else going on at the same time (UI updates) Can you post the calculate method?

Comment: calculate method is way too long to post it here :/
But I see now that every time I click on the button to set the view to my contentcontrol (MyContent.Content = new FirstView();), it takes longer to set it. Example: I click on it at the first time => needs ~0,3sec. When I click on it at the 15 time, it needs ~5sec or even more to set the content of my contentcontrol. edit: it's still the Calculation() that takes so long...

Comment: Ok,.... Calculation() is being called 100+ times now (after setting the new Content for ContentControl)... Gonna check where Calculation() is being called so often.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't disposing of your old viewmodels appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you've shown so I suspect the Calculation method. Profile it.

If the Calculation() method is too long to post, it shouldn't be in a property setter :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the solution. Every time I click on the button "FirstView", the Content of the ContentControl gets a NEW VIEW()! So every time I click on the button, it'll do:

```
MyContent.Content = new FirstView();
```

This means that there are still somehow Views in the background open... I can't explain it by myself, but if I set the View globally like

```
FirstView fw;
```

and say in the constructor of the MainViewModel

```
fw = new FirstView();
```

I can easily assign the content of my ContentControl like this (without creating a new View):

```
MyContent.Content = fw;
```

You can download a test app here: http://www65.zippyshare.com/v/89159114/file.html
It has a MainView and 2 Views. It shows my problem. If you click on the Button "FirstView", the content of the contentcontrol will be "FirstView.xaml". It has 2 textboxes, which calculate the sum and has a for-loop (for i = 0, i < 500, i++). If you calculate right at the start, the calculation takes only ~1 sec, but if you click the Button "FirstView" ~30 times and try to calculate again, the calculation takes more than 10 sec!!!
I thinks it's because of MyContent.Content = new FirstView(); You can check my program and correct me if I'm wrong or say if I'm right... Like I said, I think that this is the solution, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Yes, the previous views are still bound to the ViewModel so they are updating as well. This is why many MVVM frameworks use some sort of cache that hands out views so they get recycled and some frameworks use weakreferences so the garbage collector is able to remove the old views.

Comment: K, thanks! :)
I finished my app after several weeks and then this... Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if Calculate() isn't an async method, it blocks the UI.
You could use

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
   Calculate();
   RaisePropertyChanged(() => Bruttolohn);
});
```

Not relevant to your question, but maybe interesting:

```
if (value != _bruttolohn)
```

Strings should be compared using .Equals, as the same string can be referenced to different places in the heap.
So:

```
if (value == null || !value.Equals(_bruttolohn))
```